# Android Studio AVD Manager Creating AVDs in root directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am using Android Studio with Ubuntu and it won't create AVDs. Nothing gets created in my ~/.android/avd directory. Instead things are getting created in my /root directory. Which I guess I wouldn't care about, except of course it can't run the emulator for these AVDs if the AVDs are in my root folder. I think it's because for the Android SDK manager to be accessed in Linux, Android Studio has to be run with sudo...but then it puts the AVDs in root instead of home...

I have a few pics outlining this problem very clearly, but stackoverflow won't let me even link to them without 10 rep, what a nuisance of a restriction.

EDIT: Here is the error I get in my terminal when I try to execute the android bash script located in `/opt/android-studio/sdk/tools/`. It's the same error whether or not Android Studio is open or not.

```
 ss108 tools$ bash android 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1516)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1492)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:346)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:369)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.UpdaterData.initSdk(UpdaterData.java:252)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.UpdaterData.<init>(UpdaterData.java:120)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.SwtUpdaterData.<init>(SwtUpdaterData.java:61)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:104)
at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:88)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:407)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:390)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```

Comment: You have 10 rep now, so feel free to post those pics.

Answer (score 3):

The AVDs are created under `/root` because you are starting Android Studio with `sudo`. You need to configure the permissions so that this isn't required. The simplest solution that I have found is to install Android Studio and the Android SDK as my regular user. I install these into `$HOME/bin` so that I don't have to bother with permission issues at all. When everything is installed, my regular user account has execute permission for all the files I need.

Alternatively, you can use `chmod` (either manually or with `find`) to set the permissions on Android Studio and Android SDK files.

Comment: Thanks for the help, sorry I wasn't able to thank you and try it until now.

My android-studio folder is unpacked in a directory under my Home. I run Android Studio with the bash script studio.sh, as their Linux installation instructions say to do. The issue is that I cannot start the AVD or SDK manager without running Android Studio as root.

Running chmod +u on the .avd and .ini files of the AVD I am trying to run did not help. Neither did running chmod +x

Comment: @ssaeed You need to change the permissions of the files in your SDK installation, specifically the executables under the `tools` and `platform-tools` subdirectories. The AVD and SDK managers are started with the `tools/android` bash script. Make sure you have permission to execute this file.

Comment: I ran `sudo chmod +x` on tools/android.sh. There was no such file in platform-tools. Unfortunately, I am still experiencing the same problem.

I'm just going to use Windows for now I guess. I'd much rather use Linux, but I can't have my learning delayed by this ops issue. Hopefully Google and/or JetBrains gets it together soon. 

Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Now when I double click the SDK Manager it, gives me the loading modal, and the bar completes, but nothing actually happens after that. The AVD manager is still completely unresponsive.

If I try to run the android shell script from the terminal, I get a null pointer exception in Java.

Comment: @ssaeed please update you original question with the exact error message